# Push a segue at selected row swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, segue

I am trying to push a segue after having selected a row. I have tried various ways through other peoples questions but I am getting no where.
Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class RoutineViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView! {
    didSet {
        tableview.dataSource = self
    }
}

var routines: [NSManagedObject] = []

var stringToPass:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableview.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Routine")

    do {
        routines = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return routines.count


}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    tableview.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "R2", sender: cell)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "R2" {

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "R2", sender: self)
        }

    }
```

I do have the table working and everything, there is a save function, delete function and it fetches and updates I just cannot get it to segue to another view controller. The segue identifier is called "R2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set `tableview.delegate` to `self`.

`tableView(_:didSelectRowAt)` is the `Table View Delegate` method. Somewhere set this in your `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    tableview.delegate = self
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'll try now I hope it wasnt this simple for my mentality hahaha

Comment: happy to help 

Answer (score 0):

Try change to this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
tableview.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

performSegue(withIdentifier: "R2", sender: self)

}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "R2" {


    }

}
```

Comment: Ill give it a shot!

Comment: Erm I am still getting no input back, is there any code I need in the other .swift file?

Comment: it seem you not yet set delegate to tableview.

Answer (score 0):

For monitor any activity in **UITableView** give **delegate as self**.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView! {
       didSet { 
            tableview.dataSource = self
            tableview.delegate = self
            }
 }
```